# Sub-site group permissions with document libraries

Tags: permissions

I have a created a SharePoint site which has three user groups and three document libraries in it. Each document library is intended to be a repository for each user group. This site was created using the **Document Center site**, I'm not sure if that makes a difference at all.

However, I would like each user group to be able to navigate through the site as normal, but have no access at all to the other document libraries which are for the other users.

When I assign permissions to a group for their respective document library, they cannot access the top level page and navigate the site as normal.

When I allow 'Restricted view' permissions (the lowest level available I believe) they can navigate the site but they can also see the contents of all other users libraries which I cannot allow.

Is it possible to achieve what I want, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Provide read access to the site for all the 3 groups.
2. For the 3 document libraries, break permission inheritance and provide access only to the group which need access to a particular library and repeat the same for other 2 libraries too.

By this way, the respective group users will have access only to the document library in which they have access and as the 3 groups have read access to the site, they can roam around the site but not on the other document libraries in which they do not have access.